# Is hashmap increasing O(N+1) for every same hashcode object put in it?

Tags: java

**Is hashmap increasing O(N+1)  for every same hashcode object put in it?**

Comment: No. The [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) javadoc says (explicitly): *This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (`get` and `put`), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.*

Comment: is this a question about time or space complexity?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch question said *same hashcode* mean collision. "get" performance will degrade in case of collision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best case complexity for `put` is `O(1)` in time and space.

The average case complexity for `put` is `O(1)` time and space when *amortized* over `N` put operations.

- The amortization averages the cost of growing the hash array and rebuilding the hash buckets when the map is resized.
- If you don't amortize, then the worst-case performance of a single `put` operation (which triggers a resize) will be `O(N)` in time and space.

---

There is another worst-case scenario which occurs when a large proportion of the keys has to the same hash code.  In that case the worst case time complexity of `put` will be either `O(N)` or `O(logN)`.

Let us define `M` to be the number of entries in the hash bucket with the most entries.  Let us assume that we are inserting into that bucket, and that `M` is `O(N)`.

- Prior to Java 8, the hash chains were unordered linked lists and searching an `O(N)` element chain is `O(N)`.  The worst-case `put` operation would therefore be `O(N)`.
- With Java 8, the implementation was changed to use balanced binary trees when 1) the list exceeds a threshold, and 2) the key type K implements `Comparable<K>`.

  For large enough `N` we can assume that the threshold is exceeded. So the worst-case time complexity of `put` will be:

  - `O(log N)` in the case where the keys can be ordered using `Comparable<K>`
  - `O(N)` in the where the keys cannot be ordered

Note that the javadocs (in Java 11) mention that `Comparable` may be used:

> *"To ameliorate impact, when keys are `Comparable`, this class may use comparison order among keys to help break ties."*

but it doesn't explicitly state the complexity.  There are more details in the non-javadoc comments in the source code, but these are implementation specific.

---

The above statements are only valid for *extant* implementations of `HashMap` at the time of writing (i.e. up to Java 12).  You can always check for yourself by finding and reading the source code.

Answer (score 1):

For Hashmap's get method

- Non collision - O(1)
- In case of collision - O(log n) [Java8], O(N) [before Java8]

Java8 has started using a balanced tree instead of linked list for storing collided entries. This also means that in the worst case you will get a performance boost from O(n) to O(log n).

Check details [here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/01/how-does-java-hashmap-or-linkedhahsmap-handles.html)

Comment: How does the Balanced Tree work? Does it need the keys to be `Comparable`?

Comment: Javadocs say "Thus, performance degrades gracefully [... when .. ] many keys share a hashCode, so long as they are also Comparable. (If neither of these apply, we may waste about a factor of two in time and space compared to taking no precautions. But the only known cases stem from poor user programming practices that are already so slow that this makes little difference.)"